# spring - missing daylight adjustment after inserting timestamp in oracle db

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am writing objects of the following class to an oracle db using spring boot with hibernate jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name="signins")
public class UserSignIn
{
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="signinIdGen" , strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="signinIdGen")
    @Column(name="signin_id",nullable=false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="timestamp", columnDefinition="timestamp default current_timestamp", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date timestamp;

    @Column(name="username", columnDefinition="varchar(50)", nullable=false)
    private String username; 
}
```

I save and retrieve the objects using an interface that extends `CrudRepository` from spring boot jpa:

```
public interface SigninDao extends CrudRepository<UserSignIn, Long> {
}
```

After inserting an example `UserSignin` for which I set `signin.setTimestamp(somelong)` I see in the db that the entry has a timestamp of
`2018-08-10 15:59:48.667000`

**PROBLEM:** When I retrieve the same entry, the timestamp is -1 hour
 `"timestamp":"2018-08-10T14:59:48.667+0000"`. It seems like the `Date` timestamp has a daylight adjustment set to 0 when inserted.

Thanks for the help

Comment: In what timezone is the inserted time (2018-08-10 15:59:48.667000)?

Comment: it was inserted in BST

Comment: Ok, so what exactly is the problem? The time which is returned, is correct in this case. It's not daylight adjustment, it's just serialized as UTC.

Comment: At the time I inserted the query (August 10th) there is daylight adjustment (BST=UTC+1h no?)

Comment: Right, though i wouldn't express it that way, but in the end it's correct. But could you again specify what exactly the problem is?

Comment: sorry I think I dont get what you mean. The inserted timestamp is `2018-08-10 15:59` and I inserted it at `2018-08-10 15:59 BST`. When I retrieve it, it is `2018-08-10 14:59` while it should be `2018-08-10 15:59`. What I am trying to achieve is that the stored timestamp remembers if it had daylight saving or not. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timestamp you inserted is 2018-08-10 15:59+0100. The timestamp you retrieve is 2018-08-10 14:59+0000. It is the exact same time, just with two different timezone formattings. If you need a different formatting or different output, you just have to configure the correct timezone in the formatter for the date (post some of your code where you retrieve the timestamp and how the JSON formatter is configured if you need detailed help for that).

When you store the timestamp, it is automatically converted from the local time and stored as a UTC timestamp, and that's also what it's retrieved. So the stored timestamp doesn't need to remember if it had DST or not since the conversion happened before storing it.